# Nomenclature in QM textbook by Landau and Lifshitz

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, terminology, notation

According to [Landau and Lifshitz](https://books.google.de/books?id=neBbAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) ["Quantum Mechanics non-relativistic theory", page 6], the probability of various results of any measurement is given, in general by the following expression:
$$\iint \Psi(q)\Psi^\star (q') \phi(q,q') \,dq\,dq' $$ 
Where the function $\phi$ depends on the nature of the measurement, and $q$ is the set of coordinates of the quantum system. I have no idea why this is the case. But what makes me anxious is that the authors did not explain anywhere in the text what does $q'$ stand for. Is this a derivative of $q$? (I don't think so). So what is $q'$?

Comment: A second generalized coordinate. Think of them as $q_1$ and $q_2 $.

Comment: Which volume? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic Quantum Mechanics non-relativistic theory, paragraph 2, formula no. 2.1

Comment: I'm not sure... q is meant to be the set of all coordinates and dq is defined to be their product

Comment: Read around (2.3), it definitely is just a second coordinate, check section 14 for more discussion.

Answer (score 3):

L&L's expression
$$\iint \Psi(q)\Psi^\star (q') \phi(q,q') \,dq\,dq' $$ 
is just the "familiar" expression (in case you have some other exposure to QM)
$$\int \Psi(q)^\star ~ \hat \phi ~\Psi (q)   \,dq ~ , $$ 
a sandwich between wavefunctions of a Hermitean  operator $\hat \phi$ representing the observable. (For instance, if it were the momentum operator $\hat p$, this would be the expectation value of the momentum measurement.) *q'* is but another coordinate "like" *q*.

Later on, in eqns (3.10, 3.11) they explain their tasteful convention of representing operators through integral kernels,
$$
\hat f \Psi ~(q)= \int dq' ~ f(q,q') \Psi(q') ~,\\
f(q,q')=\sum_n f_n ~ \Psi_n(q')^\star ~~ \Psi_n(q) . 
$$

Perhaps you are more familiar with the Dirac bracket notation,
$$
\langle \psi| \hat \phi| \psi\rangle= \iint dq dq' ~ \langle \psi|q'\rangle \langle q'|\hat \phi|q\rangle \langle q|\psi\rangle ~,
$$
that is
$$
\hat \phi =  \iint dq dq' ~  |q'\rangle   \phi (q,q')\langle q|  ~.
$$

For example,
$$
\hat p = \iint dq dq' ~  |q'\rangle    i\hbar (\partial_q \delta (q'-q))\langle q| = \int dq   ~  |q \rangle \frac{\hbar}{i} \partial_q  \langle q| ,
$$
after integration by parts and collapsing the δ function, so that, 
$$
\langle \Psi|\hat p |\Psi \rangle= -i\hbar \int dq   ~ \Psi(q)^\star ~\partial_q \Psi(q).
$$